# Gmail relay will not email account on its own domain (google apps)

Tags: ubuntu, email, gmail, sendmail, relay

I am running sendmail on Ubuntu.
I've configured it all as normal to relay email via my Google apps server.
I have another account on a ubuntu VM that works just fine and it can email itself etc. I even tried setting up that account on this server, and it was still perfectly able to email itself.

So why cant I email myself at support@mydomain.com or tech@mydomain.com?

Here are the logs of the email attempt:

```
Dec 18 00:55:32 mydomain sendmail[10068]: qBHNtWTp010068: from=www-data, size=432, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201212172355.qBHNtWTp010068@mydomain.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Dec 18 00:55:32 mydomain sm-mta[10069]: STARTTLS=server, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=NO, cipher=DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Dec 18 00:55:32 mydomain sendmail[10068]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Dec 18 00:55:32 mydomain sm-mta[10069]: qBHNtWbY010069: <support@mydomain.com>... User unknown
Dec 18 00:55:32 mydomain sendmail[10068]: qBHNtWTp010068: to=support@mydomain.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30432, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Dec 18 00:55:32 mydomain sm-mta[10069]: qBHNtWbY010069: from=<www-data@mydomain.com>, size=432, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Dec 18 00:55:32 mydomain sendmail[10068]: qBHNtWTp010068: qBHNtWTq010068: DSN: User unknown
Dec 18 00:55:33 mydomain sm-mta[10069]: qBHNtWba010069: from=<>, size=2283, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201212172355.qBHNtWTq010068@mydomain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Dec 18 00:55:33 mydomain sendmail[10068]: qBHNtWTq010068: to=www-data, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31456, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (qBHNtWba010069 Message accepted for delivery)
Dec 18 00:55:33 mydomain sm-mta[10070]: qBHNtWba010069: to=<www-data@mydomain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=32559, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

What on earth could be causing this? :/ I can email other domains absolutely fine. It just seems to not be able to resolve my domain or something??

Answer (score 1):

If you setup to use a `GMail` relay, you need to set your server to authenticate as the gmail user you want to use as a relay.  Without authentication you will be able to sent do gmail, but not other domains.  Your logs seems to indicate the user you are using is unknown.

If you want to redirect mail to non-existent users like `support` or `tech`, you will need to add aliases for these in `/etc/aliases`.  You should already have aliases for some important addresses like `postmaster` and `root` defined in the file.  The command `man etc-aliases` should give you some assistance.

Comment: No, as I said I can email everyone else just fine, but when it comes to @mydomain.com emails I get user unknown, if I wanted to email lets say, example@gmail.com or example@hotmail.com it'd work just fine. My authinfo file is all setup with the right details.

Comment: @user72783 I've reread your question and hope my update helps.

Comment: The users do exist, I am sending mail from support@mydomain.com to support@mydomain.com but still getting user not found :/

Comment: @user72783 The fact you are using a from address does not mean the user exists. Do you have a corresponding system user? If not, you will need an alias entry.  I've mostly given up on validating from addresses as many legitimate bulk senders use invalid users.